# Is this series, which use the tan function, convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Below is a problem I did. Is my solution valid?

Problem:
Determine whether the series convergences or diverges. Give reasons for your answers.

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \tan \left( \dfrac{ \ln n } { n }\right) $$

Answer:

First I consider that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} a_n$
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} a_n &= \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}  \tan \left( \dfrac{ \ln n } { n }\right) \\
\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} a_n &= 0
\end{align*}
Since this limit is $0$ the series may or may not converge. All the terms of the series are positive. I am going to compare the series to:
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \dfrac{1 } { n } $$
For any small and positive real number $x$ I claim that $\tan(x) \geq x$. We know this series diverges
hence the original series diverges also.

Comment: You'll want to break out the first two terms, but yes, starting with the third term, you can straightforwardly establish that $\tan\frac{\ln n}{n} > \frac{\ln n}{n} > 1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your reasoning is almost right, indeed *eventually* (that is for $n>2$)

$$\tan \left( \dfrac{ \ln n } { n }\right)\ge \dfrac{ \ln n } { n } \ge \frac1n$$

therefore the given series diverges by direct comparison test.